# Cannot append body or data to an HTTP request with GET methods

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, next.js13

I have a next.js application and it should get data from an API with the GET method and send body together (my API need data). Below is part of the code:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "ids": [
    94751,
    94750,
    89767
  ]
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.mysite.com/cars/compare", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

this code is generated by postman. It works properly. But when I copy it in next.js application .below error occured?

> you can not send body to HEAD/GET request with fetch request (something like this).

How can I solve this? It is mandatory?

Comment: GET requests do not have bodies. Use query parameters if you need to send data. This is because a GET request simply gets a specific resource, as specified by the URL; that resource must be specified entirely in the URL.

Comment: You _can_ work around this by using POST or PUT requests. You just have to keep an eye on semantics if they're important to you and your situation; those requests are for creating and updating resources, usually.